# Not able to upgrade NPM on Ubuntu Server 16.04

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm

I'm trying to upgrade NPM on an Ubuntu Server (16.04) however, it is not upgrading at all.

```
npm -v
```

returns `3.5.2`

When I run

```
sudo npm install npm@latest -g
```

I get the following:

```
/usr/local/bin/npm -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
+ npm@5.0.3
updated 1 package in 7.414s
```

However when I check the version it still shows as `3.5.2`.
Why does this not upgrade?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) and execute commands:

```
nvm install 8.0
nvm use 8.0
```

This should bring you close to latest versions of both node and npm